# How do I update a specific number in a text file?

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, file-io

I am writing a real estate gui program that takes information from tenants such as first name, last name, apartment, etc. and stores these values in a text file. I have different classes for different options such as delete a tenant, update a tenant, add a tenant, and view all tenants. I have the classes made for adding tenants, deleting tenants, and viewing the tenants but am having trouble with the updating class. The way these tenants are added is through an array list that takes these different variables and uses a toString to upload them line by line in the text file. Each tenants information is on a different line. What I'm trying to do in the update class is make it so that when money is deposited, the balance of that specific tenant is set to MonthlyRent - deposit = balance. The problem that I'm having is trying to figure out how to read the monthlyRent and balance, set them to 2 variable to then do the calculation and update that specific part. I know that I have to delete the file and make a new updated one, I just don't know how to read that specific part and set them to the variables.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Person extends JFrame{
    File log = new File("tenantData.txt");
    
    
    static ArrayList<Person> tenantData = new ArrayList<Person>();
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int apartmentNumber;
    public String streetAddress;
    public int streetNumber;
    public String town;
    public String state;
    public float balance;
    public float deposit;
    public float monthRent;


Person( String firstName, String LastName, int apartmentNumber, String streetAddress, int streetNumber, String town, String state, float monthRent, float balance)
     {
        
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = LastName;
         this.apartmentNumber = apartmentNumber;
         this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
         this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
         this.town = town;
         this.state = state;
         this.monthRent = monthRent;
         this.balance = balance;
         
     }
     @Override
     public String toString() {
            String str = firstName + " " + lastName + ", apartment" + apartmentNumber + ", " +streetNumber+ " " +streetAddress+ ", " +town+ ", " +state+
     ". Monthly Rent: "+ monthRent+  " Balance: " + balance + "\n";
            return str;
    }
```

///////////// this is the main class's variables and constructor

```
public void buildPanel3() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            ButtonHandler4 b = new ButtonHandler4();
            label = new JLabel("Enter first and last name of tenant you would like to update");
            field = new JTextField(25);
            label2 = new JLabel("Enter the amount that the tenant has payed");
            paymentAmount = new JTextField(4);
            update = new JButton(updateTenant);
            update.addActionListener(b);
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(field);
            panel.add(label2);
            panel.add(paymentAmount);
            panel.add(update);
            add(panel);
        }
        public class ButtonHandler4 implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String str = e.getActionCommand();
                if(str.equals(updateTenant)) {
                    String line = field.getText();
                    String payment = paymentAmount.getText();
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    String firstName = parts[0];
                    String lastName = parts[1];
```

////////////////////this is the build panel and button handler for the update class. I need to figure out how to first search the file for the first and last name, then to update with the payment variable.

Comment: This seems a perfect case scenario for a DB. Files are much slower and present the sort of problems which you are precisely describing: they aren't too good at dealing with specific values. For updating a value within a row, the proceeding should be similar to the one for deletions: read all the contents into memory (an ArrayList, for example), remove/modify the given element, and write all the lines back to the file. If you prefer to stick with this format, you should better minimise the file read/writes by keeping everything on memory for as long as possible.

Comment: @varocarbas is correct about not reinventing databases. Better to acquire skills using one than reinventing one. If you're determined to avoid that, then `new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines...` is your friend

Answer (score -1):

In order to adapt a solution I had to re-order some variables.

I moved *log* and *tenantData* to another class.

My first recommendation would be to use a different delimiter to separate the values within the *tenantData.txt* file.
This will make it easier to parse to and from the file, since the data contains commas.

You can use a *tab* character, instead.
Here is a reference, *[Wikipedia – Tab-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values)*.

Since you're utilizing the *toString* to produce the output, you can replace it with the following.

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName + ' ' + lastName + '\t'
        + apartmentNumber + '\t'
        + streetNumber + ' ' + streetAddress + '\t'
        + town + ", " + state + '\t'
        + monthRent + '\t'
        + balance;
}
```

Additionally, you'll need a way to convert the line into a *Person* object.
You can add a *static* *parse* method, to the *Person* class.

```java
static Person parse(String string) {
    Person person = new Person();
    String[] strings = string.split("\t", -1);
    int indexOf = strings[0].indexOf(' ');
    person.firstName = strings[0].substring(0, indexOf);
    person.lastName = strings[0].substring(indexOf + 1);
    person.apartmentNumber = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
    indexOf = strings[2].indexOf(' ');
    person.streetNumber = Integer.parseInt(strings[2].substring(0, indexOf));
    person.streetAddress = strings[2].substring(indexOf + 1);
    indexOf = strings[3].indexOf(", ");
    person.town = strings[3].substring(0, indexOf);
    person.state = strings[3].substring(indexOf + 2);
    person.monthRent = Float.parseFloat(strings[4]);
    person.balance = Float.parseFloat(strings[5]);
    return person;
}
```

And, we'll need a way to compare *Person* objects.
This is also, within the *Person* class.

```java
boolean equals(Person person) {
    return firstName.equals(person.firstName)
        && lastName.equals(person.lastName)
        && apartmentNumber == person.apartmentNumber
        && streetNumber == person.streetNumber
        && streetAddress.equals(person.streetAddress)
        && town.equals(person.town)
        && state.equals(person.state);
}
```

From here, you'll need to create functionality to read the file, and locate the correct line.
There are a few ways to implement this.  I typically use the *[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html)* class since it offers a *[readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())* method.
You can also use the *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class, also the *[NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/package-summary.html)* framework offers the *[Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html)* and *[Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html)* classes—which, I use below to write the file, actually.

I placed this method within another class, along with the *log* and *tenantData* variables.

As a note, since the uniqueness of the *Person* object relies on numerous variables, I am using a *Person* object as the parameter to match.
As opposed to having a parameter for each individual value.

```java
/** @return null if not found */
Person find(Person person) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(log))) {
        String line;
        Person value;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (person.equals(value = Person.parse(line)))
                return value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, from here you can then update the values of the *Person* object, as needed.

In which, you'll need a way to write the data back into the file.

I found an interesting approach by the *Google AI*, where it recommended I use a *[String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))* to over-write the original value.

```java
void save(Person original, Person updated) throws IOException {
    String string = new String(Files.readAllBytes(log.toPath()));
    string = string.replace(original.toString(), updated.toString());
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(log)) {
        writer.write(string);
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

Here is a basic example, in where I create the file with 3 *Person* objects, and then update one, and save it.

```java
tenantData = new ArrayList<>();
tenantData.add(new Person("firstNameA", "lastNameA", 1, "addressA", 1, "townA", "stateA", 1, 1));
tenantData.add(new Person("firstNameB", "lastNameB", 1, "addressB", 1, "townB", "stateB", 2, 2));
tenantData.add(new Person("firstNameC", "lastNameC", 1, "addressC", 1, "townC", "stateC", 3, 3));

try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("files/tenantData.txt")) {
    for (Person person : tenantData)
        writer.write(person.toString() + System.lineSeparator());
    writer.flush();
}

Example example = new Example();

System.out.println("original");
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(example.log.toPath()))
    System.out.println(line);

Person person = example.find(new Person("firstNameB", "lastNameB", 1, "addressB", 1, "townB", "stateB", 0, 0));
Person copy = Person.parse(person.toString());
person.balance += 10;

example.save(copy, person);

System.out.println();
System.out.println("updated");
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(example.log.toPath()))
    System.out.println(line);
```

Output

```
original
firstNameA lastNameA    1   1 addressA  townA, stateA   1.0 1.0
firstNameB lastNameB    1   1 addressB  townB, stateB   2.0 2.0
firstNameC lastNameC    1   1 addressC  townC, stateC   3.0 3.0

updated
firstNameA lastNameA    1   1 addressA  townA, stateA   1.0 1.0
firstNameB lastNameB    1   1 addressB  townB, stateB   2.0 12.0
firstNameC lastNameC    1   1 addressC  townC, stateC   3.0 3.0
```

And, here is the complete code.

```java
public class Example {
    File log = new File("tenantData.txt");
    static ArrayList<Person> tenantData = new ArrayList<Person>();

    /** @return null if not found */
    Person find(Person person) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(log))) {
            String line;
            Person value;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (person.equals(value = Person.parse(line)))
                    return value;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    void save(Person original, Person updated) throws IOException {
        String string = new String(Files.readAllBytes(log.toPath()));
        string = string.replace(original.toString(), updated.toString());
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(log)) {
            writer.write(string);
            writer.flush();
        }
    }

    static class Person {
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public int apartmentNumber;
        public String streetAddress;
        public int streetNumber;
        public String town;
        public String state;
        public float balance;
        public float deposit;
        public float monthRent;

        Person() {
        }

        Person(String firstName, String LastName, int apartmentNumber, String streetAddress, int streetNumber, String town, String state, float monthRent, float balance) {

            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = LastName;
            this.apartmentNumber = apartmentNumber;
            this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
            this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
            this.town = town;
            this.state = state;
            this.monthRent = monthRent;
            this.balance = balance;

        }

        static Person parse(String string) {
            Person person = new Person();
            String[] strings = string.split("\t", -1);
            int indexOf = strings[0].indexOf(' ');
            person.firstName = strings[0].substring(0, indexOf);
            person.lastName = strings[0].substring(indexOf + 1);
            person.apartmentNumber = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
            indexOf = strings[2].indexOf(' ');
            person.streetNumber = Integer.parseInt(strings[2].substring(0, indexOf));
            person.streetAddress = strings[2].substring(indexOf + 1);
            indexOf = strings[3].indexOf(", ");
            person.town = strings[3].substring(0, indexOf);
            person.state = strings[3].substring(indexOf + 2);
            person.monthRent = Float.parseFloat(strings[4]);
            person.balance = Float.parseFloat(strings[5]);
            return person;
        }

        boolean equals(Person person) {
            return firstName.equals(person.firstName)
                && lastName.equals(person.lastName)
                && apartmentNumber == person.apartmentNumber
                && streetNumber == person.streetNumber
                && streetAddress.equals(person.streetAddress)
                && town.equals(person.town)
                && state.equals(person.state);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return firstName + ' ' + lastName + '\t'
                + apartmentNumber + '\t'
                + streetNumber + ' ' + streetAddress + '\t'
                + town + ", " + state + '\t'
                + monthRent + '\t'
                + balance;
        }
    }
}
```